# Why does my boolean variable change (C++)?

Tags: c++, variables, boolean, pass-by-reference, program-entry-point

Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bool x = false;
    if (x = true) { cout << "x is true" << endl; }
    if (x = false) { cout << "x is false" << endl; } 
    // for some reason always prints "x is true".
}
```

I was trying to figure out why I couldn't do a call-by-reference with a boolean method (yes I tested after erasing the method as well), and then I realized the boolean variable in my main method was changing on its own. Please help!

Answer (score 7):

Your if statements need double equals `==` to compare. You are assigning to your variable with `=`

Oh and `x=true` assigns to `x` and is itself is also `true`.

Comment: And many compilers warn you about code like this if you set the warning level high enough.